# cordova loading external JSON: raises a security error: how to load external json/img?

Tags: json, cordova

this simple jquery

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts', function(posts) {
    console.log(posts);
});
</script>
```

raises a security error:

> Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following
>   Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' data: gap:
>   https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'". Either the 'unsafe-inline'
>   keyword, a hash
>   ('sha256-/OMeeqrReZqs8zvhvRv51tcNO4wLgn8S7UT/XE7yUDw='), or a nonce
>   ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note also that
>   'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a
>   fallback.

I have `<access origin="*" />` in my config.xml

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I have what *may* be a similar issue (data appears to be blocked, but I'm not seeing the security error listed).